# Vim: remapping Shift-Cmd-Opt-Ctrl to Escape

Tags: vim

It seems like [this article](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/a-modern-space-cadet/) by Steve Losh has been making the rounds, and in short, it led me to remap Caps Lock to F19, and at the system level, to remap F19 to Shift-Command-Ctrl-Alt, thus giving me an entire namespace for my own keyboard shortcuts.

The problem is I enjoyed using Caps Lock as my escape key in Vim. 
I tried `:map <M-C-D-S> <esc>`, but upon sourcing, hitting caps lock doesn't do anything. I'm guessing it's because Vim expects an actual key to be pressed with the modifiers.

My question is: is it possible to have Vim read Shift-Cmd-Ctrl-Alt as Escape?

Comment: Nope, Vim does not expect anything like this. It just can’t work with any key combos that cannot be represented by internal very limited byte queue format. Thus you either need some top-level application that will translate `<M-C-D-S>` to some escape sequence for vim (better to escape itself) or to abandon the whole idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My original question suffers as an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

> You want to do X, and you think Y is the best way of doing so. Instead of asking about X, you ask about Y.

I wanted to Vim to read <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as <kbd>Esc</kbd> (while still maintaining the other crazy system-level modifications), so I asked about functionality that Vim doesn't have.

Turns out, while the answers provided above were great, on point, and informative, I just don't like being told 'no.' And I was searching for answers in the wrong problem space.

One of the applications discussed in the OP's link, KeyRemap4MacBook, is highly extensible. The documentation leaves much to be desired, but I was able to piece together a solution in line with my original question. This diverges sharply from the original topic of "map stuff in vim," and for that I apologize, but I hope to leave this in posterity for the one poor soul that needs this.

Simply put, the previous article recommends adding this to KR4MB's 'private.xml' file:

```
<item>
    <name>Remap Caps Lock to Hyper</name>
    <appendix>OS X doesn't have a Hyper. This maps Left Control to Control + Shift + Option + Command.</appendix>

    <identifier>caps_lock_to_hyper</identifier>

    <autogen>
        --KeyToKey--
        KeyCode::F19,

        KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
        ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L
    </autogen>
</item>
```

([modified slightly](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2012/11/shift-control-option-command-on-caps-lock/) for <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>)

This can instead be changed to:

```
<item>
  <name>Caps Lock to Hyper OR Escape</name>
  <appendix>Caps Lock should be remapped to F19 (80) in PCKBH</appendix>
  <appendix>This remaps F19 to "Hyper" aka Cmd-Shift-Ctrl-Alt...</appendix>
  <appendix>...but, when pressed alone, F19 sends only escape</appendix>
  <identifier>remap.hyper2hyper_escape</identifier>
  <autogen>
      --KeyOverlaidModifier-- 
      KeyCode::F19, 

      KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
      ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L, 

      KeyCode::ESCAPE
  </autogen>
</item>
```

This tells the system that whenever <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is pressed alone, it's actually <kbd>Esc</kbd>, but if it's pressed in conjunction with any other key, it's <kbd>F19</kbd>.

Comment: Excellent! I read a blog post on this somewhere, but now I can't find it. Did you write about this elsewhere?

Comment: @jrhorn424 No, not yet anyways. Sorry! :)

Comment: @jrhorn424 this might be the blog post you were thinking of: http://brettterpstra.com/2012/12/08/a-useful-caps-lock-key/  
Now I just need to find a way to accomplish this in windows.

Comment: @BrandonPugh Thanks! The usual way to do key switchery on Windows is AutoHotkey. Not sure it would work with something this complex, but it could be worth a look.

Comment: This answer helped me realize I was also looking in the wrong place. I am on a Mac using Karibiner Elements to map my 'Hyper' key. There was a user-created script on their 'Import more rules from the Internet' page that took care of this perfectly. https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/#caps_lock

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't map four modifiers. Not even three, Not even two. And, well… not even one.

"Modifiers" are called "modifiers" for a reason: they are used with normal keys to "modify" their meaning. The Shift, Alt, Cmd and Ctrl keys don't do anything on their own and Vim rightfully does nothing but wait for further keypresses when you hit them.

Additionnaly, Vim's input mechanism is a bit "old school", most probably to keep it consistent over the multiple platforms it may run on. It won't register more than one modifier with a normal key. That means that, if the terminal doesn't eat them up (which it does), you can only do `<C-…>` or `<S-…>`. The Alt key is not really a working solution because of how many terminal emulators deal with it and the Cmd key is Mac-only and only works in MacVim anyway.

At that point, if you are ready to mash four keys together to emulate the function of only *one* key (which in itself is rather silly), you might as well simply use `<C-c>` which, AFAIK, works everywhere. Your left hand will thank you.

Comment: It is all not about consistency, it is about design flaws: when vim was created Bram was not thinking anybody will need combos which terminals were unable to send. Hence internal format is `<80>..` where `..` is a key from termcap database for special keys like `<Del>` or `<F1>` and raw control character for `<C-smth>` combos. Termcap database is completely unrelated to win32 or gtk gui, but you still see the same string for `echo "\<F1>"`. Nobody could prevent it from being `<80>F1<80>` or anything you like, though at the start it was also having performance and supportability benefits.

Comment: The couple of mailing list threads I've read on the subject actually went a little bit above my head because of lack of immediate interest on the subject so, yeah, I'm admittedly a little fuzzy on those low-level details. What I've understood, though, is that Vim's input system can't really deal with that kind of scenario because of design choices. Those threads were rather old so I wouldn't bet on any progress on that front in the near future. Thanks for providing more background.

Comment: Thanks, both of you, for the information here. Vim never ceases to amaze me with its unending amount of rabbit holes.